# Jquery Mobile Select Popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, select, mobile, popup

I need to open a popup if a specific select option is selected. Basically, if the user selects "Add Custom", a popup will come and the user can add a custom category.

Here is the code: http://jsbin.com/uxahuc/3/edit

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

While you are trying to open a popup on a select menu, it would want you to give some delay before you can open the pop up. So in your code for popup open, set a timeout for say 100ms, and then do popup('open').

See a demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ds345/j2ARC/).

JavaScript code would look like:

```
 $("#message-commands").on("change", function (event, ui) {
    var value = event.target.value;

    switch (value) {
        case "add":
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#both').popup('open');
            }, 100);
            break;
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$('#category').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'custom') {
        $("#addCategory").popup("open");
    }
});
```

Also i would highly recommend not doing your SQL in java script if possible it makes your database very susceptible to SQL injections.

Comment: Thank for the advise. But this app is not going t access anything online. All the data will be locally stored. So I don't think it will an issue. But thanks heaps